# undefined method table_alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems, gemfile

When starting my rails application I get the following error. Can someone give me a hint where to search for an error?

```
undefined method `table_alias' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000000339df20>
```

This is my gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.12)
      actionpack (= 3.0.12)
      mail (~> 2.2.19)
    actionpack (3.0.12)
      activemodel (= 3.0.12)
      activesupport (= 3.0.12)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.5.0)
      rack (~> 1.2.5)
      rack-mount (~> 0.6.14)
      rack-test (~> 0.5.7)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activemodel (3.0.12)
      activesupport (= 3.0.12)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5.0)
    activerecord (3.0.12)
      activemodel (= 3.0.12)
      activesupport (= 3.0.12)
      arel (~> 2.0.10)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
      mysql2
    activeresource (3.0.12)
      activemodel (= 3.0.12)
      activesupport (= 3.0.12)
    activesupport (3.0.12)
    antlr3 (1.8.12)
    arel (2.0.10)
    builder (2.1.2)
    composite_primary_keys (3.0.0.b3)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.1)
    erubis (2.6.6)
      abstract (>= 1.0.0)
    fast_xs (0.8.0)
    i18n (0.5.0)
    in_place_editing (1.2.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.19)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.7.5)
    libxml-ruby (2.3.3)
    mail (2.2.19)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.19)
    mysql (2.8.1)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    net-sftp (2.0.5)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.9)
    net-ssh (2.5.2)
    newrelic_rpm (3.4.1)
    nokogiri (1.5.5)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.2.5)
    rack-mount (0.6.14)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.5.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.0.12)
      actionmailer (= 3.0.12)
      actionpack (= 3.0.12)
      activerecord (= 3.0.12)
      activeresource (= 3.0.12)
      activesupport (= 3.0.12)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.0.12)
    railties (3.0.12)
      actionpack (= 3.0.12)
      activesupport (= 3.0.12)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.4)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ruby-ole (1.2.11.4)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    simple_xlsx_writer (0.5.3)
      fast_xs (>= 0.7.3)
      rubyzip (>= 0.9.4)
    spreadsheet (0.7.3)
      ruby-ole (>= 1.0)
    surpass (0.1.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.33)
    will_paginate (3.0.3)
    xsd_xml_parser (0.0.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord-mysql2-adapter
  antlr3
  composite_primary_keys (= 3.0.0.b3)
  in_place_editing
  jquery-rails
  json
  libxml-ruby
  mysql
  mysql2
  net-sftp
  net-ssh
  newrelic_rpm
  nokogiri
  rails (= 3.0.12)
  rubyzip
  simple_xlsx_writer
  spreadsheet
  surpass
  will_paginate
  xsd_xml_parser (= 0.0.4)
```

Comment: Where is that error happening? File/line number. The Gemfile.lock has nothing to do here I believe. You are trying to call the method 'table_alias' for an object that doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is - are you calling that method `table_alias` anywhere? Maybe you forgot to define that function... Try this on the project directory:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep "table_alias"
```

This will find that method in any file in your project structure - if it exists.

Another possibility that comes to mind is that since this is ActiveRecord, you haven't initialized your database... Have you run the `rake db` commands?  For example, we use ActiveRecord for session store, so initializing looked something like this:

```
bundle exec rake db:create:sessions
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

There is also a `rake db:setup` command.

Comment: I did not call this method, seems like on of the gems I was using, called it, so updating all of the gems seemed to solve this problem...